# Separating jQuery and creating classes/namespaces? (OOP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, class, namespaces

I recently came across DUI (Diggs user interface) which implements jquery and gives you the ability to create classes, with jQuery etc.

I can't seem to find any reviews. I saw one comment to say it wasn't up to much.

I was wondering what everyone else is using with regards to separation of concerns with jQuery.

Do you use some kind of implementation of class, inheritance and namespaces?

Any info really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was a pretty elegant way to do things, and there are worse ways to go than following John Resig:

- http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

As far as namespaces and whatnot, I would keep it flat. Generally, you will not run into a lot of collisions unless you're trying to crowd into the $ function.